# Post Screenshot of APP to wall

Tags: screenshot, facebook-iframe, facebook-apps

How would I make a button that when clicked the user of the app will be posting a screenshot of the canvas page they are on and have it posted to their wall? And maybe add some comments with it as well.

Answer (score 0):

you would have to require the user to add some additional plugin to their browser. There are many plugins that do this - for example [clipboard.com](http://www.clipboard.com/) provides this functionality. 
To the best of my knowledge, these extensions actually make a request themselves (in the back-end) to the url you are currently on and takes the screenshot from that url on the actual server.  From there it can be shared and commented on.
However with out some external utility I don't think this functionality is possible.

hope this helps...